# Copying objects from one bucket directory folder to another bucket folder using transfer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, transfer

I'm wanting to use google transfer to copy all folders/files in a specific directory in Bucket-1 to the root directory of Bucket-2.

Have tried to use transfer with the filter option but doesn't copy anything across.

Any pointers on getting this to work within transfer or step by step for functions would be really appreciated.

Comment: Why not use `gsutil`. Much faster and easier to configure.

Comment: Can you explain some more of what you have tried already and what didn't work?  Maybe an example source bucket layout and transfer configuration?  Effectively, the equivalent of a [Minimum Reproducable Exmple](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Yes I can use gsutil but wanted to us the Storage Transfer Job and schedule it frequently. This will need to be done multiple times a day and automated as there are so many files.

Comment: The more I look at this the more I think it'll need to be done through Google Functions with storage finalize trigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, a few things to consider here:

1. You have to keep in mind that Google Cloud Storage buckets don’t treat subdirectories the way you would expect. To the bucket it is basically all part of the file name. You can find more information about that in the [How Subdirectories Work](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/audit-logging) documentation.
2. The previous is also the reason why you cannot transfer a file that is inside a “directory” and expect to see only the file’s name appear in the root of your targeted bucket. To give you an example:

   - If you have a file at `gs://my-bucket/my-bucket-subdirectory/myfile.txt`, once you transfer it to your second bucket it will still have the subdirectory in its name, so the result will be: `gs://my-second-bucket/my-bucket-subdirectory/myfile.txt`
3. This is why, If you are interested in automating this process, you should definitely give the [Google Cloud Storage Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries) a try.
4. Additionally, you could also use the GCS Client with Google Cloud Functions. However, I would just suggest this if you really need the Event Triggers offered by GCF. If you just want the transfer to run regularly, for example on a cron job, you could still use the GCS Client somewhere other than a Cloud Function.

   - The [Cloud Storage Tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/storage) might give you a good example of how to handle Storage events.

Also, on your future posts, try to provide as much relevant information as possible. For this post, as an example, it would’ve been nice to know what file structure you have on your buckets and what you have been getting as an output. And If you can provide straight away what’s your use case, it will also prevent other users from suggesting solutions that don’t apply to your needs.

Comment: Thanks. Point taken regarding posts. Yes part of the reason for looking at Functions was the event trigger. I'll have a look through your links and thanks for the explanation it has clarified why this was problem.

Answer (score 1):

I reproduced your issue and worked for me using gsutil. 
For example:

```
gsutil cp -r gs://SourceBucketName/example.txt gs://DestinationBucketName
```

Furthermore, I tried to copy using Transfer option and it also worked. The steps I have done with Transfer option are these:

1 - Create new Transfer Job
Panel: “Select Source”:

2 - Select your source for example Google Cloud Storage bucket

3 - Select your bucket with the data which you want to copy.

4 - On the field “Transfer files with these prefixes” add your data (I used “example.txt”)

Panel “Select destination”:

5 - Select your destination Bucket

Panel “Configure transfer”:

6 - Run now if you want to complete the transfer now.

7 - Press “Create”.

For more information about copy from a bucket to another you can check the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/moving-buckets#step_2_copy_objects_from_your_old_bucket_to_your_new_bucket).

Comment: Thanks but there are a couple of things which I needed. needs to be done through GCS Transfer or Google Functions instead of gsutil. Also needs to copy an entire sub directory rather than a single file.

Comment: I also tried it with a folder and is working. 
In step 4 instead of prefixes use your full name of the folder and it will work.

Comment: Sure that's what the answer above does but as I say I cannot use gsutil. Needs to be cloud functions.

Comment: Just to clarify I provided 2 possible solutions. The first one is with gsutil command and the second one is using Transfer as you asked in the question title. Also it's easier with Transfer instead of Cloud Function, if you have to use Cloud Function you have to check "REST APIS" from the same documentation.

Comment: Yes but unless I'm missing something with transfer I can only use the whole bucket as the source, not a directory?

Answer (score 0):

try this in Cloud Shell in the project

```
gsutil cp -r gs://bucket1/foldername gs://bucket2
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes that's what I'm after however not using the gsutil. Either need to use the Storage Transfer or Google Functions. I think GCS Transfer will be too limiting so trying to figure out a Functions approach.

Comment: You can use cloud functions, use the python client library and the Cloud Storage API. Why would you want to use Cloud Functions instead of GSUtil? is this something you want to automate?